# Resize gif while keeping background transparency

Tags: transparency, gif, mac

Keep in mind I'm using Mac's Preview, hardly a powerful graphics tool. Anyways, I am attempting to resize a few gif files (not factoring in graphics quality, I simply want them larger in size). Should be easy enough? Well I went to Preview's Change Size menu, altered the dimensions to roughly what I wanted them to be, and saved them. It seemed alright at first, but when I opened the game where the gifs were used, the frames all had black backgrounds, while the unaltered originals *were* transparent. Preview does seem wildly unoptimised for gifs, not even having a function to play them, so I think its safe to say that's the problem. So what is the simplest method of resizing a gif, without getting my problem, and which definitely works on Mac?

### Note

This is different from other "make gifs transparent" questions, because I'm not looking for a way to make them transparent - the gifs already *are*. This is about the resizing process.

Also, for posterity, I'll add that it is a Pokemon fan game, which uses the old png sprites by default. Replacing these pngs with gifs works just fine, except that every now and then some of those gifs are hilariously disproportionate, with no larger-resolution gifs available on the net.

Comment: You could try https://ezgif.com/resize (no personal experience with it)

Comment: You could try: https://ezgif.com/resize (No experience with it personally)

Comment: @Metis And we have a winner! It seems this was a Preview-specific issue, because that sire worked wonders. Write it up as a solution and I'll mark it as the answer, if you like, thanks

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1362352/how-do-i-resize-an-animated-gif-and-keep-transparency. I also tried ezgif.com but it produces banding and reduces color depth, while `ffmpeg` doesn't produce banding using a custom palette.